# Asymmetric cost assignment for SVM

Tags: r, svm, r-caret

I need to assign different costs based on error:

•   False negative – 10

•   False positive – 1

```
svmFit <-   train(Y ~ .,
            data = credit.train,
            method = "svmRadial",
            preProc = c("center", "scale"),
            tuneLength = 8,
            cost=1:10,
            metric = "ROC", 
            probability = TRUE, 
            trControl = trainControl(classProbs = TRUE,summaryFunction=twoClassSummary)
```

Here the cost is mis-classification and an algorithm will select cost with maximum AUC as we chose the metric to be ROC.

But I need to find out a way to penalize by 10 if it is false negative and 1 if it is false positive. Currently it will penalize both with same value.

Comment: What software are you using? Looks like R, but which package?

Comment: Yes, I am using R with caret package. I am happy to use any package as long as I get the solution.

Comment: I am using R with Caret Package. I am open to using any package as long as I get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

`caret` has some wrappers for [cost-senstive learning models](http://topepo.github.io/caret/Cost_Sensitive_Learning.html). Try one of those.

Max